# change Filebeat config to add fields

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat

I am trying to use the filebeat.yml file for the first time. Since, the logs are being logged in a different country and sometimes I see an abrupt jump in the logs visibility. It might be (not sure) because previously those services were not online for the logs to ES clusters. Anyways, I want to get only the date and time and display that as a field in kibana logs.
For the solution, I am trying the script processors as follows:

```
- script:
      lang: javascript
      id: my_filter
      tag: enable
      source: >
        function process(event) {
            var str = event.Get("event.message");
            var time = str.split(" ").slice(1,3).join("@");
            event.Put("event.start_time",time);
        }
  - timestamp:
   #format the start_time layouts then assign to @timestamp
      field: start_time
      layouts:
        -'2006-01-02@15:04:05.999'
```

I noticed was that,
in `message : [hsjdfjsdgf-23hjsbdf-2346dsad] [2020-11-25 22:31:16.795] [INFO]` but @timestamp is `Dec 16, 2020`. Hence, the counts of the service hits is very different. Do I need to delete anything and restart?

Further, It took me a lot of time to write this script and combat with for correct syntax. Since, I am going to write lot of `if else` and slicing them based on condition, Any easier way to do this?

Comment: Do you send your data from filebeat to elasticsearch directly or do you use a logstash component to write into the elasticsearch cluster?

Comment: @YLR only filebeat. I came to know about https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date-processor.html as well but it doesn't look like filebeat format.

Comment: I advise you to put a logstash between filebeat > elastic, to be able to process/filter your dataflow. Keep in mind that filebeat must have a minor footprint as possible on the host, and if you need to have process/filter or another "heavy" operation it doesn't be present on filebeat side (just imagine if you have to update this on each filebeat agent, that could be a hard and long task)

Comment: @YLR can I not use dissect processor? I am trying but the fields are not showing up in kibana. Can you help?